# IBM Cloud: Empty result from ResourceControllerV2.list_resource_instances()

Tags: python, ibm-cloud

I'm getting an empty result set from Python `ResourceControllerV2.list_resource_instances()` trying to programmatically get all the resource instances while connected to an IBM cloud research *joint* account.

However, I'm having no issues getting said result-set via the cli while connected to the same joint account.
Moreover, 'ResourceControllerV2.list_resource_instances()' works as expected when authenticated using the IAM_API_KEY of my personal account (meaning it returns the resource instances of that freemium account in its entirety).

Usage example:

```
def get_resource_instances():
"""return the entire resource list created by user, except cloud foundry based name-spaces. """
     authenticator = IAMAuthenticator(IAM_API_KEY)
     resource_controller_service = ResourceControllerV2(authenticator=authenticator)
     return resource_controller_service.list_resource_instances().get_result()
```

Comment: This looks like the Python SDK and I added that tag. You say you that you get an empty result set, but that you also have success. Provide more details. (And this is Stack Overflow, not an IBM internal forum, etc.)

Comment: Thanks @data_henrik, I've edited the original message to make my intentions clearer.

Comment: And do you have checked the scope of the IAM API key? Who has issued it, what privileges are attached?

Comment: Found the answer by trail and error and posted it. Appreciate the help @data_henrik.

Answer (score 0):

Apperantly you have to specify the resource_group_id in case it isn't default.
Thanks for your time @data_henrik.
I hope this piece of information will be useful to others.